# Are Spiderman's Web Shooters Biological or Artificial?

Tags: marvel, comics, spider-man

I am confused. I thought Spiderman's ability to shoot web was through biologically built-in nodules in his wrists due to the mutations that happened when he was bitten by the spider.

But then in MCU films and the most recent Spider-verse film by Sony, we see that he's using artificial shooters on his wrists.

So which is more original to Spider-canon? Is his ability to shoot/produce web supposed to be biological as part of the mutation? Or was it always artificial?

Answer (score 3):

In the comics, at least until the age of nonsense (early-mid 90s, my opinion only) his web shooters were artificial. He built them himself and invented the formula because he was a genius I guess.

In the Sam Raimi movies, they were biological features.

[image]

Comment: doh! finally one I could answer and its a dup!

Comment: LOL. Sorry. I couldn't seem to get another question about this to appear, hence why I asked, but then they found one above.

Comment: Seems like a biological nodule would hurt or at least would have been a really WEIRD feeling to get used to for Parker. At least when he had first discovered his abilities. 

Hence why I could see why an artificial shooter would make more sense from that perspective.

Comment: A more germane question would be how he hides the belt and wrist bands under a skin-tight outfit.

Comment: Truth. I could see maybe in the MCU, the suit Stark makes for him having the fluid somehow built into the black web "ribs" in the suit's structure, thus that's what holds the web fluid that then fires out of the shooter. But for the older comics and what-not, I guess that was left up to the reader's imagination not to think about that.